# Distinct 0 and 1 on histogram with logscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, histogram, logarithm

Is there any way to plot a histogram in `matplot lib` with log scale that include 0?

`plt.ylim( ymin = 0 )` doesn't work because `log(0)` is `NaN` and matplot lib removes is... :(

Answer (score 2):

So I assume that you want to have a logscale on the y axis from what you have written.
Obviously, what you want to achieve won't be possible. log(0) ist NaN because log(0) is not defined mathematically. You could, in theory, set ylim to a very small number close to 0, but that wouldn't help you either. Your y axis would become larger and larger as you approach 0, so you couldn't display whatever you want to show in a way that would make any sense.